# Best Features for Term Level Clustering

Tags: twitter, cluster-analysis, k-means, text-mining, feature-extraction

At the moment, I am working on a project that related to mining Twitter data. The aim of the project is to find the themes that can be used to represent the set of tweets. To help us finding the themes, we came up with an idea to do term level clustering. The terms are some important concepts that already extracted using some TextMining tools.
Well, my main question is, what are the best features to define term similarity? In this project, due to an insufficient amount of data, I am doing the unsupervised learning, which is clustering using the k-means algorithm.
I do have some extracted features. As I understand, one way to know the semantic (not actually) meaning of a term is by seeing the context of which the term is mentioned. Therefore, what I have at the moment are preceding and following WORD and POS of the term. For instance:

```
I drink a cup of XYZ
She had a spoon of ABC yesterday.
```

By seeing the preceding word and POS - cup/NN and of/IN for XYZ and spoon/NN and of/IN for ABC - I knew that XYZ and ABC might be a liquid material or component. Well, it sounds very naive, in fact, I don't get the good clusters. In addition to the previous features, I have some named entity types that I considered as features. For instance, entity type like Person, Location, Problem (in medical), MEDTERM etc.

So, what are the common features for term level clustering? Any comments and suggestions would be appreciated. I do open to any guidance, such as paper, link etc. Thanks

EDIT: In addition to those features, I've extracted the head nouns of each term and considered it as one of my features. I am thinking of using a head noun in the case for multi-word terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me see if I understood correctly what you need. You already extracted/found the terms you want as centres of your clusters, and now you want to find all terms which are similar to them so they get grouped in the proper cluster?.

In general you need to define a similarity measure (distance) and here is the main point, what you want that similarity distance to measure or determine. If you are looking for term to term similarity, just letters then you can try things like Levenshtein distance for example, but if what you want to find are contextual similar terms, even they are written in a very different way but could mean the same thing, thats different from Levenshtein pretty much harder to do.

What is important to keep in mind is that you need a measure of similarity to find the similar terms. What I see you call features some named entity types, normally k-means is bad when dealing with non continuos data.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your feedback. Ya, you are right, i've found the terms and try to group the similar terms. +1 for mentioning Levensthein. However, I would like to group terms that lexically different but might be refer to the same concept. As I mentioned in the example above (I've edited my post). So, what are the others algorithm for non continuos data? thanks

Comment: One thing could be word2vec: https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/